# Good php alternative to bcrypt encryption when it's not available?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, bcrypt

I just learned that my host provider doesn't offer bcrypt on shared hosting.  They suggested that i use mcrypt but I'm not so sure how secure it is.  What is the best alternative to bcrypt?

Answer (score 1):

This is like comparing apples and pears. Bcrypt is a key derivation function for passwords. Mcrypt is a cryptographic library.

The biggest issues with mcrypt is the lack of a good random number generator, and a lack of good examples of how to use the library. I would give a meager 5/10 for design.

If you need a PHP version of bcrypt then check these links out:

- [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)
- http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Which means you can choose bcrypt using an openssl wrapper or directly in PHP. Check your provider which is supported, and don't forget that bcrypt/scrypt deliberately use CPU cycles and/or memory accesses to slow things down. Your provider may not like that too much (depending on the traffic of course).

Answer (score 0):

Asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362103/alternative-to-bcrypt-when-saving-passwords-in-php-5-2)

> The `hash_hmac()` function seems to be a reliable system to generate
>   hashes. The hmac is not a hash function itself, it improves existing
>   hash algorithms like sha or ripemd instead. Example of how to use:

```
hash_hmac('ripemd256', $dataToHash, $key);
```

> More information to the hmac you can find in Wikipedia - HMAC.

Comment: Ok i've heard of this before.  Thanks for showing how to use it though.  But I guess I should of asked if there was an alternative "one-way" encryption function, that's similar to bcrypt?

Comment: Yes, that changes the answer. Be sure to edit that in your question.